# How to stop updating null values in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a sql procedure which perfectly works. please find it below.

```
declare
cid number;
cadd number;
ctras number;
pr varchar(2);
vad number;
cursor c1 IS
select ac_tras, cust_id, cust_addr from customer_master;
cursor c2 IS
select pr_adr from customer_address where cust_id = cid and cust_addr = cadd;
BEGIN
open c1;
LOOP
fetch c1 into ctras, cid, cadd;
EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
OPEN c2;
LOOP
fetch c2 into pr;
if pr='Y'
THEN EXIT ;
ELSE
UPDATE customer_master 
set cust_addr = (select cust_addr from customer_address where pr_adr = 'Y' and cust_id = cid) where ac_tras = ctras;
END IF;
EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
Close C2;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
END;
```

Everything works fine. The problem is, The update statement updates null if the sub query returns null. How to avoid this.

Comment: well what value do you want to assign to cust_addr if the subquery is null?  Or you don't want do update at all?

Comment: It returns null, implying you have null `cust_addr` values; or it doesn't find a matching record at all?

Comment: It should not update at all

Comment: What happens if you would make the actual table column a NOT NULL column ?

Comment: It doesn;t update. Throws an error like cannot update null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the subquery doesn't find a matching row then the master table will be updated with null, because ther eis no filter to stop that. A common way to avoid that is to check that a matching row does exist:

```
UPDATE customer_master 
set cust_addr = (
  select cust_addr from customer_address
  where pr_adr = 'Y' and cust_id = cid)
where ac_tras = ctras
and exists (
  select cust_addr from customer_address
  where pr_adr = 'Y' and cust_id = cid)
;
```

It doesn't really matter which column name you use in the `exists` clause; some people prefer to use `select *` or `select null` but it seems to be a matter of taste really (unless you specify a column you aren't going to be using later and which can't be retrieved from an index you're using anyway, which could force an otherwise unnecessary table row lookup).

You could also do a merge. [And has been pointed out several times now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28148010/266304), you don't need cursors or any PL/SQL to do this.